# Why my bedroom lights are on when a light in another room is turned on

Tags: bulb

During night, when all the lights are off and it is very dark in the room, I noticed that my bedroom lights turn on barely when a light is turned on in another room.
The light is very barely visible and I would not notice them if it was during the day, only when it is very dark. I am using Philips Hue in my bedroom.

Comment: Are the bedroom lights on any unusual type of switch (e.g. a dimmer, or a remote-controlled switch) rather than just the usual toggle?

Comment: I agree duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have not set up your lights properly through your app?
In pictures this is the sequence to follow. I would also make sure your serials are inputted properly and not reacting off other light settings, since Hue bulbs can receive signals from other bulbs (rather than just your Hue Bridge),

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]